# TYPO3 FAL image output for Flexform

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x, flexform

I know similar questions have been asked here before but this is more a sort of follow-up question.

I receive this from my data array inside a Fluid template: `{data.flexform_imageRight}`. Which returns 2243049 in this case. I also have this line: `<v:uri.image src="2243049" treatIdAsReference="1" />`

[image]

When I use `<v:uri.image src="{data.flexform_imageRight}" treatIdAsReference="1" />` I get the exeption `Could not get image resource for ""`, but when using `<v:uri.image src="2243049" treatIdAsReference="1" />` (hardcoded number) the path is shown correctly.

I'm aware that a string is returned and I need an integer for this to work but I'm starting to think that might not be the problem as the error suggests an empty input as the src value.

Could anybody shed some light into my mystery, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast variables in Fluid like this: `{data.flexform_imageRight as integer}`.

That's a function somewhere hidden in the docs.

Comment: This is really weird. When debugging this, I get the correct number / ID of the reference. When using it inside the `f:image src` I get the error `No file reference (sys_file_reference) was found for given UID: "0"`.

Comment: I guess your variable did not contain the sys_file_reference.uid as you expected? Maybe it contained the image object and should have been included with `f:image image=...`?